# ID components may not include unresolved tokens: ${Token[TOKEN.199]}-ec2 when using CfnParameter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am trying to use a CfnParameter in the AWS Python CDK to pass in a value: this will then be included in subsequent resource names.

```
    _resource_name_param = CfnParameter(self, 
                                       'resourcename', 
                                       type='String',
                                       description='base name for res')
    self._resource_name = _resource_name_param.value_as_string
```

e.g. used in ec2 naming:

```
instance_name=self._resource_name + '-ec2'
```

When I run cdk deploy --parameters resourcename=xyz-123 however it returns an error...

```
jsii.errors.JSIIError: ID components may not include unresolved tokens: ${Token[TOKEN.199]}-ec2
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to resolve by using --context instead of --parameter:

```
self._resource_name = self.node.try_get_context('resourcename')


cdk deploy --context resourcename=value
```